# Find and replace special x character from string in php

Tags: php

I am working with the stripe webhook system and they include a special x character in their subscription description field. Below is an example.

```
"description": "1 × Base Package (at $25.00 / year)",
```

When this description is entered into a utf8 formatted email the character is lost and replaced with an A character.  I have tried a grocery list of functions attempting to find this character.  I wish to simply replace it with either a standard x or html character.

Comment: use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which will make it `&times;`

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it was an encoding issue.  That worked.

Comment: @James Are you sure that your email has the right header? You set before? `$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). This function is binary-safe.

```
$string = "1 × Base Package (at $25.00 / year)";

$strClean = str_replace('×','x',$string);
```

The first 'x' is the orginal Unicode-Char, second 'x' is ASCII. This becomes visible with a special debugger.

```
$string: string(36) UTF-8   1\x20\u{d7}\x20Base\x20Package\x20(at\x20$25.00\x20/\x20year)

$strClean: string(35) ASCII 1\x20x\x20Base\x20Package\x20(at\x20$25.00\x20/\x20year)
```

To make the difference more visible in the code, you can also use

```
$strClean = str_replace("\u{d7}",'x',$string);
//or
$strClean = str_replace("\xc3\x97",'x',$string);
```

These are ultimately just different spellings for the same [Unicode Character “×” (U+00D7)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D7)